# Volley Listeners not being called

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using `volley` to send a `JSONObject` to my server and then receive a response back. When I run my code, in debug mode, I can see `parseNetworkReponse()` of `JsonObjectRequest` being called and I can see that the library was able to successfully parse the network response without throwing any errors. However, `deliverResponse()` and subsequently my `onResponse` listeners are not being called. I am using the `JsonObjectRequest` class to post and receive `JsonObjects`. Here is part of my code:

Main application:

```
        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
        jso.put("mac", "XX");

        VolleyRequest.post("http://something", jso, applicationCntxt, new IResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
```

VolleyRequest.post method:

```
 public static void post(String url, JSONObject payload, Context context,       final IResponseHandler rqHandler)
    {
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //stuff
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //stuff
        }
    };

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, payload, listener, errorListener);
    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, 1f));

    VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

}
```

Anyone know what is causing the on response listeners to not get called?  I know that `Volley` is sending my post request and parsing the response correctly. I can see that from the `debugger` and my server is not throwing any errors.  It just does nothing after parsing the network response

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the listeners in Main Application? You never call them in your post method.

```
public static void post(String url, JSONObject payload, Context context,       final IResponseHandler rqHandler)
{
Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        rqHandler.onResponse(response)   ;     
        //stuff
    }
};

Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        rqHandler.onError(error)   ;
        //stuff
    }
};

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, payload, listener, errorListener);
jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, 1f));

VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

}
```

Comment: Oops, I actually do have that. I just forgot to c/p in above. But in any case, I have breakpoints set up inside


public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        rqHandler.onResponse(response)   ;     
        //stuff
    }



And they are never triggered which makes me think that the listener is not being called.